# Append a ionic-slide-box with angular elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to append a div from my controller but its not working.

```
var angularView = angular.element('<ion-scroll direction="y"> <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" ng-repeat="result in news.results | limitTo:1"> <ion-slide class="slider-class" ng-repeat="result in news.results"> <h1>Element to be repeated</h1></ion-slide> </ion-slide-box> </ion-scroll>');
  var compileView= $compile(angularView)($scope);
  $('#newsView').append(compileView);
```

i don't wanna use a directive. Any work around for this? Thank you.

Comment: If you are using angular then why you need jquery ?

Comment: Provide more details be specific.

Comment: Any error in console? Do you injected $compile in controller?

Comment: @KevalBhatt even if i use angularjs instead of jquery it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jenny No errors. I am injecting $compile everything is working fine. If i repeat the same contents inside a div it will display. Doesn't work inside ionic slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem of ionic slides which you can't append from controllers.

you have to append items inside the slide-box

Answer (score 2):

Try using :
`$('#newsView').html(compileView);`

It should add the html text to the element. Also have you checked the value of `compileView` ?

Comment: By using 'compile' the angular bindings are set and ready to use.

Comment: i can see my data getting repeated when i console log compileView. its present in nextElementSibling. But its not getting appended.

Comment: @MihailStancescu   angular.element('#newsView').html(compileView); does the same thing. then why Jquery ?

Comment: @KevalBhatt you are right, it should work ok, since Angular has built-in jqLite. @GuruajBhandarkar can you post the contents of the compiled `compileView`?

Comment: @MihailStancescu tried repeating the same contents in a div tag, It works. Doesn't work for ionic tags :(